# Refreshing Maya UI during script?

Tags: python, user-interface, refresh, maya, keyframe

I'm making a script that goes through a skeleton and for each joint checks how many keys it has and for each key will write the position and rotation values out to a file.

but when I select a joint through code, it does not update the timeslider to show the joints keyframe ticks. And my next step is to use the findKeyframe command to find the first keyframe, and then just find the next and the next for the amount of keys the joint has. But since it dosn't update the UI all I'm getting is the same value over and over.

I've tried using timeControl to set showKeyframes and force an update, which just doesn't seem to work, and I've also tried the refresh command which does update the current view, but no the UI.

Are there any other way I might be able to refresh the UI in the middle of a script using python?

Comment: If you want to export all keys to a file, I'm quite sure there is a method to simply request all keys from an animation curve. Then you can write them to a file.

Comment: I agree with Haggi, you don't have to refresh the timeline to get all the value from a animated curve

Comment: The thing is that I'm writing it as a certain filetype that needs the time, xyzw rotation and xyz position, in that order for each key. So if I got all the keys for a curve and then wrote that to the file, it wouldn't work in the format. And if certain curves had keys at different times it would also not work.

Comment: With the keyframe command you can query a value from a animcurve at a arbitrary time value so this should be no problem even if the keys are not evenly distributed.

Comment: Although I didn't manage to find a way to query a value at a specific time with the keyframe command, I could do it with the getAttr command, so I got it working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: haggi is correct, you don't have to change the current frame or have the object selected in order to get a key's value. Use `cmds.keyframe("obj.attr", q=True)` to get all frames of that plug, then `cmds.keyframe("obj.attr", q=True, time=(10, 10), eval=True)` to get the value at a specific time. In fact, changing the current frame will make your script run significantly slower so it's best to avoid that.